# IsWebSocketRequests not working in mono

Tags: c#, http, websocket, mono, httplistenerrequest

i connected to both HTTP and webSockect in .NET on windows system,its working fine then i moved the same project to mono to test on linux system using Mono but it giving me a false case that is webSocket connection IsWebSocketRequest is becoming false

```
 if (httpListenerContext.Request.IsWebSocketRequest==true)
 {
   //some logic
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:8080/");
 httpListener.Start();
```

**I tried in this way it worked for me**